# How to use LR test (likelihood ratio test)?

Tags: regression, logistic, likelihood, aic

I have used LR test for testing my models. My model 1 is a logit model with control variables and Model 2 is a model with both predictors and controls. But the LR test is coming to be non-significant and alternatively, my AIC value for model 2 is higher than model 1. How should I interpret this result?

Comment: The AIC is a less stringent criterion for model selection than a likelihood ratio test. While the AIC penalizes the number of parameters in the model, the LRT requires that the test statistic exceeds a critical value to declare the more complex model as statistically significant. Technically speaking, hypothesis testing and model selection are completely different enterprises.

Answer (score 1):

A likelihood ratio test tests whether the additional parameters present in the larger model are jointly different from zero (i.e., whether any of them are different from zero). Failing to reject the null hypothesis indicates that the smaller model is to be preferred. For you, this is model 1.

In general, you should favor the model with the smaller AIC. If model 1 has a smaller AIC, it is to be preferred. The LR test and AIC are telling you the same thing: there isn't evidence your predictors improve model fit beyond the controls.